# What does .class mean after a class name

Tags: java

What does `.class` mean in, for example, `MyClass.class`? I understand that when you put the name of a class and the point it is used to access its static fields or methods, but that doesn't relate to '.class'

Comment: debemos culpar a google translate entonces.

Comment: Or be disappointed that despite all other accomplishments, we still have not laid out a path to unite the world in language and understanding.

Comment: @irreputable I guess you meant *deberíamos*.

Comment: @TimBender try to unite programmers in one computer language first...

Answer (score 22):

`SomeClass.class` gets the `Class<SomeClass>` type which you can use for programming using the [reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html).

You can get the same type if you have an instance of the class using `instance.getClass()`.

You can check out the [documentation here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html). For example, you can:

- get the names of fields and methods, annotations, etc.
- invoke methods, get constructor to create new instances of the class
- get the name of the class, the superclass, package, etc

Answer (score 11):

When you write `.class` after a class name, it references the [`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) object that represents the given class (formally, it is a named *class literal*). The the type of `NombreClase.class` is `Class<NombreClase>`.

E.g., `NombreClase.class` is an object that represents the class `NombreClase` on runtime. It is the same object that is returned by the `getClass()` method of any (direct) instance of `NombreClase`.

```
NombreClase obj = new NombreClase();
System.out.println(NombreClase.class.getName());
System.out.println(obj.getClass().getName())
```

Answer (score 7):

You can add `.class` to the name of any class to retrieve an instance of its *Class* object.

When you use `Integer.class` you reference an instance of `Class<Integer>`, which is a typed class object.

I always thought this was a field member that got added by the compiler, but it looks like it's really just syntactic sugar.

Comment: before you access a static field, you need the class, so it'll be circular if the class is a field. actually, `A.class` is simply compiled to `Class.forName("A")`, so nothing magical.