# underlying procedure for someMethod(SomeClass.class)

Tags: java, reflection

in hibernate to create criteria we use

```
Criteria criterea=session.createCritera(SomeClass.class)
```

It may be available in some other examples too but I am not able to understand the structure of these type of methods.

**NOTE** this is an example I am trying to put to understand use of `SomeClass.class` like arguments

my question here is what is purpose of `SomeClass.class` ? why do we need it, what is the advantages of using it as argument.

**Edit** its not a duplicate but have string connection to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15101794/what-does-class-mean-after-a-class-name)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is the Class object (java.lang.Class)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453349/what-is-the-class-object-java-lang-class)

Comment: Although it asked about a *particular* use-case of the `ClassName.class` argument, I wrote a few general words about this in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30750881/3182664

Comment: @Marco13 thanks they really helped :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What is this `.class` syntax?

If you attach `.class` to the end of a class name, you get the `Class<T>` object corresponding to the class.

Examples:

- `String.class` returns an instance of `Class<String>`
- `Integer.class` returns an instance of `Class<Integer>`

#### What can you do with a class object

Reflection! If you have access to a class object, you can do all kinds of cool stuff! You can call methods, get and set values of fields...

#### Why is this used in Hibernate?

I haven't used hibernate before, but this syntax is used in other libraries as well, especially in ORMs or JSON serializers. I'll use JSON serializers as an example as I'm more familiar with those.

In a JSON serializer, you need to give it a class object because it needs to get all the fields that you want to serialize to JSON. It uses reflection to get and set the values of those fields, then convert them to JSON. When it deserializes JSON, it finds the field that needs to be set with the name in the JSON. These operations require a `Class` object because without it, how can Java know which class should it find the field? Also, to create a new object with reflection, a `Class` is needed as well!

Comment: short story : are you trying to say that we use `SomeClass.class` inside method argument only to create instance of it  but since reflection is a heavy process, then why not find other alternatives

Comment: @HelloWorld because a library like hibernate cannot possibly know the names of the classes you created without using a `Class`. That's why it cannot create an instance of your class by `new SomeClass()`

Comment: I think I may be wasting your time but what I am thinking from your answer is passing `SomeClass.class` as argument will force reflection to find relevant data eg Class name,name of fields to be operated and this can be done using writing long lines of code to, now what I want to ask is *is that good to adopt this approach, or long lines are good*?

Comment: @HelloWorld I don't know how you can get the values of fields in an unknown class by writing long lines code. Even if there is a way, I think you should stick with reflection for now because premature optimization is the root of all evil. If you found out that using reflection is really extremely slow, try using the long lines of code and see what happens.

Comment: and I got this one liner `A.class is simply compiled to Class.forName("A")` from thread(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15101794/what-does-class-mean-after-a-class-name), which explains almost many things

Answer (score -1):

Hibernate provides many ways to handle the objects in relation with RDBMS tables.
One way is Session interface providing createCriteria() method which can be used to create a Criteria object.
As name says criteria, it is useful to execute queries by applying filtration rules and logical conditions of programmer wish.

For example:

```
Criteria obj=session.createCritera(Galaxy.class) // say SomeClass is Galaxy.class
List results = obj.list();
```

Here, criteria query is one which will simply return every object that corresponds to the Galaxy class.

We even can restrict the results with criteria, example add() method available for Criteria object to add restriction for a criteria query.
Following is the restriction to return the records with planet which has 7.4 billion population from Galaxy class:

```
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Galaxy.class);
cr.add(Restrictions.eq(“planet”, 75000000000));
List results = cr.list();
```

Comment: i think you misunderstood the question